# how to get the unique max data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below table

```
userid      comp_dd     coursecode  qualification   course_id   course      passyear    totalmarks             func        stream
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------------
60          26          1           High School     15          Class 10     26          67                     2           All Subject
60          26          2           Senior Secondry 15          Class 12     26          85                     2           Commerce
60          2010        3           Graduates       4           B.Tech/B.E   2010        54                     1           IT/Computers
60          2013        4            Post Graduates 9           M.com        2013        98.5                   2           Commerce
```

i wanted to get the unique record of max coursecode, the output should be

```
userid      comp_dd     coursecode  qualification   course_id   course      passyear    totalmarks             func        stream
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------- -----------------
60          2013        4            Post Graduates 9           M.com        2013        98.5                   2           Commerce
```

There will be many records of the different userids

Comment: *"i wanted to get the unique record of max coursecode, the output should be "* what in case of ties? Meaning the same max coursecode value.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.coursecode = (select max(t2.coursecode)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.userid = t.userid
                     );
```

You can also do this with window functions, but the correlated subquery is often faster with the right index, which would be on `(userid, coursecode)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the table by `coursecode` descending and get the 1st row:

```
select top 1 *
from tablename
order by coursecode desc
```

This will work only if there are no duplicates in the column `coursecode` since it will fetch only 1 row, but I guess this is the case because you say:

> i wanted to get the unique record of max coursecode